# SpringBoot Data exception handling

Tags: java, spring, date, spring-boot

I have a spring boot post controller which has a date as parameter with a specific format, the problem is that if the user submits the form with a different format the app would crash and i'm not really sure how i should deal with this:(
Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/findFlights", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String findFlights(@RequestParam("from") String from, @RequestParam("to") String to,
            @RequestParam("departureDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy") Date departureDate, Model model) {

        List<Flight> flights = flightRepository.findFlights(from, to, departureDate);
        if(flights.isEmpty()) {
            model.addAttribute("msg", "No flights were found!");
        }else {
            model.addAttribute("flights", flights);
            foundFlights = true;
            model.addAttribute("foundFlights", foundFlights);
        }

        return "displayFlights";
    }
```

Basically if the submitted date would be something like: 22-22-2018 it would give me this exception:

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date] for value '22-22-2018'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [22-22-2018]
```

But if the date is for example:10-15-2018 it will work...what would be the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do one of the following:

- You can receive date as a String, convert it in your service and return required error info to client
- implement Exception handler advice and return required answer/error to client
- receive data as a json, and on json write your own formatter ( string to date ) and then if format is wrong you can throw your own exception